# Mysql AVG to ignore zero

Tags: mysql, null, zero, average

I need to perform an avg on a column, but I know that most of the values in that column will be zero. Out of all possible rows, only two will probably have positive values. How can I tell mySQL to ignore the zeros and only average the actual values?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Assuming that you might want to not totally exclude such rows (perhaps they have values in other columns you want to aggregate)

```
SELECT AVG(NULLIF(field ,0)) 
from table
```

Comment: Thanks, this will probably be the best option because yes, I do have values in the other columnns!

Comment: this works great -- especially when you have more than 1 aggregate function in your query

Comment: Thanks! I was struggling with this one for a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 5):

You could probably control that via the WHERE clause:

```
select avg( field ) from table where field > 0
```

Comment: Only if the rows where field is greater than zero are the ones I'm worried about. Unfortunately in this case, there are 3 other columns I need to check where that may not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

```
select avg(your_column) 
from your_table 
where your_column != 0
```

Comment: That works, except there are other fields I wish to pull at the same time as one big average.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert zeros to `NULL`, then `AVG()` function will work only with not `NULL` values.

```
UPDATE table SET column = NULL WHERE column='0';
SELECT AVG(column) FROM table;
```

Comment: Yeesh.  Changing existing data to make a `SELECT` work?  I think I'm gonna puke...